# Rails 3 build a select tag with has_many belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Based on following models

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
end
```

I want to have in my companies/_form a select tag containing all the countries

I think that the `Company.new(params[:company])` in `companies_controller#create` can create the association between company and the selected country

I'm running rails 3.0.0, what is the best way to achieve that?

thanks for your insights

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`collection_select` should do the trick for you:

```
collection_select(:company, :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select country')
```

The above code assumes that the countries table have a `name` column. If it doesn't, replace the fifth parameter with whatever the column of the country name is.

`:prompt` means that you're forcing the user to choose one country.

Find more information in the [Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select).