# Calling created Objects in Rails Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, scaffold, rails-generate

I am new to Rails and creating a football results app, I did a `rails generate Scaffold Team name:string form:string` then I added a few teams to the table, my next step I tried was to create a Fixtures table that stores teams, so I did `rails generate Scaffold Fixture week:string homeTeam:team awayTeam:team homeScore:integer awayScore:integer` when I tried to update the database doing a `rake db:migrate` I am getting an error undefined method:team I understand rails does not like the way I specify them teams as type team.

How can I go about getting this to work, as when creating a fixture I want to be able to choose from a list of teams already stored in a teams table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a random aside, the convention in ruby/rails is to use underscores as opposed to camelCase for variables and methods.

On to your actual question! You need to setup relationships yourself in the generated `Team` and `Fixture` models. Scaffolding can help you setup the relationships though by getting the correct foreign keys in place.

For the Fixture scaffold, generate it like this:

```
rails g scaffold fixture week:string home_team_id:integer away_team_id:integer home_score:integer away_score:integer
```

Note that `g` is a shortcut for `generator` and the generator doesn't need anything to be capitalized.

Now, in your `Team` model you'll want to define your relationship to the `Fixture` and vice versa (I'm no sports expert, but wouldn't naming it `Game` make more sense?):

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :home_games, :class_name => Fixture, :foreign_key => :home_team_id
    has_many :away_games, :class_name => Fixture, :foreign_key => :away_team_id
end

class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => Team
    belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => Team
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I got that working, when I try create a new fixture I have to give the homeTeam or awayTeam a value between to 0-19(the team id) if I have 20 teams?  How could I make a change to the form to display the teams in a drop menu for the homeTeam and awayTeam fields?

Comment: Like this, in your _form view partial for Fixture: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763963/rails-3-build-a-select-tag-with-has-many-belongs-to-association